# Style class xforms-disabled-subsequent added to help icon automatcially

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have used xforms:help control in a form. When i navigate from this particular page to other pages and come back to original page, an unexpected css class (xforms-disabled-subsequent) is added to xforms:help control which hides the help icon image.

```
<xforms:help>Help Text</xforms:help>
```

Can you please suggest some solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, but it may be something else as well. So we can further help with this, I suggest you create a minimal, stand-alone XForms page that reproduces this problem. Then you can update your question to include that example, and post a quick comment to this answer saying you did so.